# A KhanAcademy geometric series word problem about doses

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Niklas takes a dose of 25 mcg of a certain supplement each day. The supplement has a half life of 4 hours, meaning that 1/64 of the supplement remains in the body after each day.

How much of the supplement is in Niklas's body immediately after the 12th dose?

English is not my first language so I was wondering, since he a takes 25 mcg dose per day,that means that the 12th dose must be taken on the 12th day, right? why wouldn't (25/64)*11+25 be a right answer apart from solving it using geometric series?

Comment: $25(1+{1 \over 64}+\cdots+ {1 \over 64^{11}})$. The 12th dose is taken 11 days after the first. For example, the 10th dose is in his system for two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the supplement stopped decaying one day after being ingested, then $25/64$ mcg would remain in his body for each day he takes the supplement, and your answer would be correct.

However, that's not quite what the problem implies (you are correct about the $12$th dose being taken on the $12$th day, though).

---

The supplement continues to decay after the first day, so two full days after he takes the first dose, the first dose would have decayed by another factor of $64$, while the second dose would only have decayed by a single factor of $64$, meaning that he would have
$$\frac{25}{64^2}+\frac{25}{64^1}$$
mcg left in his body immediately before he takes the third dose, and
$$\frac{25}{64^2}+\frac{25}{64^1}+\frac{25}{64^0}$$
mcg of the supplement in his body immediately after taking the third dose. In other words, the amount of the supplement left in his body (in mcg) immediately after taking the $n$th dose can be expressed as
$$25\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{64^i}$$

Comment: So on the 12th day the first dose will be 25/(64^11), right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.